# Linq expression not working as expected

Tags: c#, linq

I want to select some values from a collection of strings, I wrote it one using LINQ and one using a `foreach` statement.

With the `foreach` version I get a list of about 300 entries.

```
List<string> res = new List<String>();
foreach (var l in anchors)
{
      if (l.Attributes["href"] != null)
      {
          res.Add(l.Attributes["href"].Value);
      }
}
```

With the LINQ version I get `null`:

```
IEnumerable<string> res2 = anchors.Select(l => l?.Attributes["href"]?.Value);
```

Comment: What is `anchors`? Did you try to materialize the output of `res2` by using `anchors.Select...ToList()`?

Comment: You have to use `Where` to filter.  Currently you're not filtering out the `null` values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the linq, you're getting null values as well and adding it to your enumerable. It's not identical to your foreach. Change it to:

```
IList<string> res2 = anchors.Where(l=>l.Attributes["href"] != null).Select(l => l.Attributes["href"].Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The [.? syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dn986595.aspx) returns `null` if the item it is applied to returns `null`. In this case, `null` is added to the output.

With the check `if (l.Attributes["href"] != null)` it is not added to the output.

To mimic that in LINQ, add a `Where`clause.